# Как сравнить множество строк и подобрать верную последовательность?

Tags: python, python-3.x

На вход приходит `n` и `n-ое` кол-во строк. Строки состоят из последовательностей букв английского алфавита. Задача подобрать такую последовательность, чтобы начало каждой строки совпадало с концом(по 3 символа брать для проверки) другой. Ответ должен выводиться в строке, которая отображает в какой последовательности вывести начальную последовательность строк.

Как такое реализовать?

Сам додумался только как принимать эти строки:

```
n = int(input())
spis = []
for i in range(0,n):
    c = input()
    spis.append(c)
```

Но дальше не могу сдвинуться. Идей совсем нет(

Написать надо стандартными средствами `Python`

Вот таким образом получил список совмещаемых и нет:

```
a = int(input())
spis = []
res = ""
good = {}
bad = {}
for i in range(0,a):
    c = input()
    spis.append(c)
for i in spis:
    for c in range(0,len(spis)):
        if (i[:3] == spis[c][-3:]) and (i!=spis[c]):
            good.update({spis[c]:i})
        else:
            bad.update({spis[c]:i})
```

Как теперь отсюда вывести подходящее и сформировать нужную строку?

Comment: то есть вам нужно понять можно ли из принятых строк составить последовательность, которую вы описали?

Comment: Да, нужно в именно это

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё я напутал, не так надо...

Нужно построить ориентированный граф, где узлы - трёхсимвольные концы и начала, а дуги - исходные строки. Если строка кончается на 'abc', она является входящим ребром (дугой) для 'abc', а если начинается - то исходящим.

Потом для полученного графа найти эйлеров путь [e-maxx](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/euler_path), [itmo](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0)

---

старый ответ пока оставлю

Проверить для каждой строки, с началом каких совпадает её конец, и построить орграф, где узлы - строки, а дуги - совпадения.

Граф может выглядеть как список смежности (список списков `A[][]`_, для i-й строки `A[i]` содержит список номеров строк, с которыми совместим конец `spis[i]`

```
a = int(input())
spis = []
for i in range(a):
    spis.append(input())

A =[[] for _ in range(len(spis))]
for i in range(len(spis)):
    for c in range(len(spis)):
        if (spis[i][:3] == spis[c][-3:]) and (i!=c):
             A[c].append(i)
print(A)


4
123456
456789
456999
999123

[[1, 2], [], [3], [0]]
```

Затем найти эйлеров путь для данного графа. Описаний алгоритма в сети немало, на Python можно воспользоватьcя `networkx.eulerian_path`

Comment: К сожалени, это всё желательно написать пользуясь стандартными средставми `Python`, потому не подходит(

Comment: networkx не подходит - значит, ручками

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Смог получить список подходящих и нет, можно ли как-то из этого получить желаемое?

Comment: Нет, update же заменит значение для ключа c, а не добавит ещё одно..  Добавил построение списка смежности на списках (на  словаре тоже можно)

Comment: Ааааа, точно -_-

Comment: Так, чёт не догоняю где этот список `A` вписать -_-

Comment: A =[[] for _ in range(len(spis))]

Comment: Пишет такое: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: см. добавил пример

Comment: Ткс, теперь остаётся придумать только алгоритм для вычисления правильной последовательности и всё. Спасибо)

Comment: @DGDays Я радикально ошибся, гамильтонов путь с эйлеровым спутал. Добавил, как можно свести задачу к эйлерову.